# RSA ImportRSAPrivateKey says wrong univercal class value

Tags: c#, rsa, c#-8.0

I have an RSA private key file, without a password, and a certificate file. I can successfully use those with curl via `curl -E file.crt --key file.key ....` and the call succeeds. Now I want to do that from C# but it throws an exception of:

> The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '16', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '2'.

I'm trying to decode like so:

```cs
var key = File.ReadAllText(path)
        .Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty)
        .Replace("\n", string.Empty);

using var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(key), out _);
```

Comment: This is most likely due to your key. The code works for me if the key is a valid PEM encoded private key in PKCS#1 format. I can reproduce your error message when I use a private key in PKCS#8 format with PKCS#1 header and footer, which is invalid (PKCS#1: BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY, PKCS#8: BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY). Try `ImportPkcs8PrivateKey()` instead of `ImportRSAPrivateKey()`. Note that .NET provides methods to import PEM keys *directly*, e.g. `ImportFromPem()` (*valid* keys of course). If the problem persists, post a non-production test key.

Comment: Thank you!  From googling I thought I had a PKCS1, but when I switched to using `ImportPkcs8PrivateKey` it now works perfectly.